# How to import&change moodle's boost font

Tags: sass, moodle

I'm trying to change my font so that it affects my whole moodle.

The font is coming from an scss file from bootstrap.

I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372448/is-it-possible-to-import-fonts-from-the-directory-with-scss), however using that is not working.

I've also seen this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47118679/moodle-3-3-2-change-default-font) and the [moodle guide](https://docs.moodle.org/33/en/How_to_add_custom_fonts_in_a_theme), and that did not work for me aswell.

I'm using Moodle 4.15

This is my current code :

```scss
// Body
//
// 1. Remove the margin in all browsers.
// 2. As a best practice, apply a default `background-color`.
// 3. Set an explicit initial text-align value so that we can later use
//    the `inherit` value on things like `<th>` elements.

@font-face {
  font-family: 'RoCo';
  src: url('/theme/boost/font/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  margin: 0; // 1
  font-family: 'Roco';
  @include font-size($font-size-base);
  font-weight: $font-weight-base;
  line-height: $line-height-base;
  color: $body-color;
  text-align: left; // 3
  background-color: $body-bg; // 2
}
```

I get this error when the page tries to load: [image]

My path is indeed correct, since Follow link redirects to the file.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or isn't this the way to change the font at all?

Edit: Forgot to tell, but this code refers to the _reboot.scss file from '/theme/boost/scss/bootstrap/_reboot.scss'

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient and clean way is to create a boost child theme :

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_theme_based_on_boost

https://docs.moodle.org/402/en/How_to_add_custom_fonts_in_a_theme

A brutal way of imposing your font is to use this rule (in scss) :

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'FontName';
        src: url([[font:theme|fontname.eot]]);
        src: url([[font:theme|fontname.eot]]) format('embedded-opentype'),
        url([[font:theme|fontname.woff]]) format('woff'),
        url([[font:theme|fontname.woff2]]) format('woff2'),
        url([[font:theme|fontname.ttf]]) format('truetype'),
        url([[font:theme|fontname.svg]]) format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
}

body{
    *{
        font-family: FontName !important;
    }
}
```

Watch closely on how the url is indicated. [[font:theme|fontname.eot]]

Comment: I don't see how making another theme just to change a font makes sense, since what i'm going to change (if so) isn't much and  it's easy to do on boost itself, it's just the font. And isn't my code above the same as the one you gave me ?

Comment: Well it does : You should never touch the core code or the theme you're not the author. Why? Because what you'll write will disappear as soon as you update moodle.
Secondly : 
How : '/theme/boost/font/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf' is exactly the same as : [[font:theme|RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf]] ?! You have to use [[]] and before the name of the font you have to use "font:theme|" and its moodle which'll translate the url.

Comment: Ah, I see, i didn't think those "[]" mattered, also didn't know it would just exclude my changes once it updated, thanks